# Set "Splash Screen" color for Android TV App

Tags: android-tv

How can I set/change the color of this animated screen for my app?

[image]

Comment: hey i have upload android TV app with splash screen google reject my app when upload without splash screen google like my app. i want to add splash screen how to do that with android TV app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Finally I've figured it out.

This color is taken from `Theme`. You should overwrite the `android:colorPrimary` to change this color.

Comment: And if you're using an `AppCompat` theme, you just need to use the `colorPrimary` attribute

Answer (score 1):

This is called "Changing Launcher color"
To customize the color of this animation, set the android:colorPrimary attribute of your TV app or activity to a specific color.

```
<resources>
    <style ... >
      <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

For More info, you can check this link
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html